# C - can sscanf read from the same string it's writing to?

Tags: c, string

I have the following code

```
int myInt;
sscanf(str, "%d=%s", &myInt, str);
```

Will this be valid? Is there a better way to do this if I have it in a loop?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this wil usually work because it seems like the source string will always be >= the result string, and that would seem to cause deterministic and as-specified results.

But I still wouldn't do it.  Library functions typically have `restrict`-qualified parameters in order to allow for optimizations and prefetch.

Don't tempt the compiler.

Comment: +1 I just checked the C99 standard and the arguments are indeed specified as `restrict` which basically means it's UB to send the same string in the VA list.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the %n conversion specification - *chars read so far; int* parameter required*. [CStdLib.html#fscanf](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html#fscanf)

Worth noticing. The standard say, about **%n**:

- No input is consumed.
- Corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.

  - Into which is written the number of characters read ***so far***.
- Does ***not*** increment the assignment count returned on completion.
- If includes an assignment-suppressing character or a field width, the behavior 
  is undefined.

<sup>Ref. ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §7.19.6.2</sup>

As concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    char *str = "12345=blabla 1313=blah "
                "333=hello 343=goodbyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
    char buf[15];
    int lt;

   /*                        +----- limit read to buffer length -1
                             |                +--- store read length here
                             |                |                        */
    while (sscanf(str, "%d=%14s%n", &n, buf, &lt) == 2) {
        fprintf(stdout,                   
            ":: '%s' :: \n"
            "Num: %d\n"
            "Str: %s\n"
            "Tot: %d bytes\n\n",
            str,
            n, buf,
            lt);
         str += lt;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Should give something like (overlong %s input breaks loop):

```
:: '12345=blabla 1313=blah 333=hello 343=goodbyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee' :: 
Num: 12345
Str: blabla
Tot: 12 bytes

:: ' 1313=blah 333=hello 343=goodbyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee' :: 
Num: 1313
Str: blah
Tot: 10 bytes

:: ' 333=hello 343=goodbyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee' :: 
Num: 333
Str: hello
Tot: 10 bytes

:: ' 343=goodbyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee' :: 
Num: 343
Str: goodbyeeeeeeee
Tot: 19 bytes
```

How one would like to handle input longer then buffer could be many. I.e. check if eof `str` and if not re-alloc. Start out with buffer of length = str, etc.

Note that numbers > INT_MAX or < INT_MIN is undefined behavior (). Will (normally?) be truncated to INT_MAX or INT_MIN respectively when using the "%d" specification.

I.e.:

```
"1234533333333333333=blabla", read by "%d%s" =>

Num: 2147483647
Str: blabla
Tot: 26 bytes consumed
```

One way to tackle this is to use `strtol` etc., which, if number is > limit is defined to set value to MAX value for type and set `errno = ERANGE`. [CStdLib.html#strtol](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html#strtol)